# How to control SendKeys.Send{"tab"} property in Datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, sendkeys

I am writing the code in datagridview cell enter event as

```
private void dgvGoodsRecpt_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvGoodsRecpt.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{tab}");
    }
}
```

This code will send the tab to next cell ,if the current cell is `ReadOnly true`.

It is working well but here my problem is that my datagridview last column is `readonly true` and the next controls are `txtAmount1.Text` and `txtAmount2.Text`.

When I keep on pressing Tab key the focus is going to `txtAmount2.Text`. But the next to datagridview is `txtAmount1.Text`. The focus is going to the next control of the imidiate control after datagridview. The focus supposed to go to the `txtAmount1.Text` control. What should I do? Please help me.

Comment: have you checked the tabindex of the textboxes?

Comment: Yes Mr.AbZy.. Those are in correct flow...

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of predefined string constants for non-alphanumeric keys. For example, `{TAB}` is for a Tab key. Here is MSDN article with all constants: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You may also consider using `SendKeys.SendWait` instead. This method will ensure that target application processes sent key before your application continues. For example:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

`SendKeys.Send("\t");`